# how to save dataframe in mongodb using pyspark?

Tags: mongodb, dataframe, pyspark

```
my_spark = SparkSession \ .builder \ .appName("DGLE") \ 
 config("spark.mongodb.input.uri", "mongodb://127.0.0.1/local.DGLE") \ getOrCreate() 
JDBC.write.format("com.mongodb.spark.sql.DefaultSource").option("spark.mongodb.output.uri", "mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/local.DGLE").save()
```

This is my code, do not know where and what is the error, please help

```
my_spark = SparkSession \ builder \ .appName("DGLE") \ .config("spark.mongodb.input.uri", "mongodb://127.0.0.1/local.DGLE") \ .getOrCreate() 
JDBC.write.format("com.mongodb.spark.sql.DefaultSource").option("spark.mongodb.output.uri", "mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/local.DGLE").save()
```

---

Comment: Could you please explain you problem more. not just the code

Comment: Also please your code. I tried to edit but I dont really know how it should exactly be. Please edit your question unless I have to flag it

Answer (score 2):

Efficient way to write into mongodb from pyspark is to use [MongoDB Spark Connector](https://docs.mongodb.com/spark-connector/master/python/write-to-mongodb/). Connector will convert the data into BSON format and save it to mongodb. Let's say you have spark dataframe named df which you want to save in mongodb. You can try:

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession, SQLContext
from pyspark import SparkConf, SparkContext
sc = SparkContext()
spark = SparkSession(sc)   


df.write.format("com.mongodb.spark.sql.DefaultSource").mode("append").option("spark.mongodb.output.uri","mongodb://username:password@server_details:27017/db_name.collection_name?authSource=admin").save()
```

If you are using notebook write this at the top-

```
%%configure
{"conf": {"spark.jars.packages": "org.mongodb.spark:mongo-spark-connector_2.11:2.3.2"}}
```

If you are using spark-submit command:

```
spark-submit --conf spark.pyspark.python=/usr/bin/anaconda/envs/py35/bin/python3.5 --packages org.mongodb.spark:mongo-spark-connector_2.11:2.3.1 file_name.py
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def save(message: DataFrame):
    message.write \
        .format("mongo") \
        .mode("append") \
        .option("database", "db_name") \
        .option("collection", "collection_name") \
        .save()
    pass
```

And this is how the SparkSession will look like

```
spark: SparkSession = SparkSession \
    .builder \
    .appName("MyApp") \
    .config("spark.mongodb.input.uri", "mongodb://localhost:27017") \
    .config("spark.mongodb.output.uri", "mongodb://localhost:27017") \
    .config("spark.jars.packages", "org.mongodb.spark:mongo-spark-connector_2.12:3.0.1") \
    .master("local") \
    .getOrCreate()
```